# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error while importing pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I am trying to import `pandas` library in my `jupyter notebook` using `python` but am getting the below error.

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Error-**

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7dd3504c366f> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    122 else:
    123     try:
--> 124         from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
    125     except ImportError:
    126         msg = """Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in get_code(self, fullname)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in get_data(self, path)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__config__.py'
```

I was able to `import` the library till very recently. But am facing this issue since I tried to upgrade some of the libraries to their more recent versions. Can someone please help to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin rights to C://? I can see you are using the base python environment. You could try using a virtual environment in order to avoid this issues:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Thanks Jesus!! I was able to resolve the error. The error was because I had previously tried installing some new libraries using "conda install" in the anaconda promt. When I later tried installing all the libraries using "pip install" I stopped getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error. The error was because I had previously tried installing some new libraries using "conda install" in the anaconda promt. When I later tried installing all the libraries using "pip install" I stopped getting the above error.