# permission denied pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, pandastable

I have an issue with pandastable:

When I want to import pandastable to display data frame in tkinter, I got an error :
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/me/.config/pandastable'

Thanks

I've already uninstall/install it but it doesn't change anything. Do anybody have a solution ?
I work on vscode with jupyter notebook, my python version is 3.9.7

Comment: Maybe this question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368495/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-error-while-importing-pandas-libra

Comment: @kabooya , the OP is about [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable). Your suggestion is about pandas.

Comment: See [Issues for Pandastable: 'Permissions error'](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/issues/155).